# ScrollView with FrameLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-framelayout

I am trying to use scroll from ScrollView to expand, collapse a header I have. I cannot use the new support library because that project does not compile with latest SDK and I am doing it manually. If I use it with a WebView or another Layout it works but with a FrameLayout it does not. I am using that Frame to load Cordova content and I tried lot of solutions like add minHeight, set viewport, add the Frame into another layout.

The basic xml code is that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerIselling"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollViewExt
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameCordova"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="220dp"/>
    </ScrollViewExt>
    <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/header"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="220dp">
             //Here header content
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To collapse/expand the header I get the scrolling values and I use them to make the header bigger or smaller.

With the layout I have, the frame is not matching parent and is not using the scroll from ScrollView, it is using the scroll of Cordova's WebView and I can get the ScrollView events touching outside the Frame but there is not content to scroll and it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Little tip: Inside a ScrollView, you can't define a children with `"match_parent"` because always take the size of ScrollView! but you can add any layout with prefixed size (for example `layout_height:"1000dp"`), or add dynamically by code like a `ListView`

Comment: Ok, I tried that but it still not working. I have set the height to 1000dp and it is not increasing nothing.

Comment: Where you set the height?

Comment: I set it to the FrameLayout and I tried also setting it programatically to Cordova WebView

Comment: Try to set "wrap_content" to ScrollView

Comment: Still the same problem, the height of the frame is not increasing and it is not using the scrollview

Comment: Ok, probably i found the problem, the onScrollListener of ScrollView detect the scroll of the layouts inside, but if you use a WebView(Cordova), you can't detect the scroll, try to set a touchListener at WebView

Comment: I will try to link the onTouch of the WebView with the ScrollView onScrollChanged.